# Use GNU versions of basename() and dirname() in C source

Tags: c, posix, gnu, dirname

How do I use the GNU C Library version of `basename()` and `dirname()`?.

If you

```
#include <libgen.h>
```

for dirname
You're already getting the POSIX, not the GNU, version of `basename()`. (Even if you

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

As far as I know there is no conditional importing in C. Is there a gcc specific trick?

Comment: `basename with dirname` means nothing to me

Comment: You don't want to combine GNU basename and POSIX dirname. There exists no GNU-specific version of dirname, so calling POSIX dirname and GNU basename on a path such as "/home/user/" (with a trailing slash) will give you a dirname of "/home" and an empty string for the basename, completely dropping the "/user" component of the path. For this reason, I think it's best to avoid the GNU version of basename altogether.

Comment: FYI: You can find the source code for GLibC impls here:
`dirname()`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/dirname.c;hb=HEAD
 , `__xpg_basename()`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/xpg_basename.c;hb=HEAD
 , `__basename()`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/basename.c;hb=HEAD
 , `libgen.h`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/libgen.h;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 10):

Just write it yourself and give it a different name than `basename`. This GNU insistence on creating alternate non-conforming versions of standard functions that can be written in 1-3 lines is completely batty.

```
char *gnu_basename(char *path)
{
    char *base = strrchr(path, '/');
    return base ? base+1 : path;
}
```

This way, your program will also be more portable.

Comment: And your trivial implementation will have problems with "/" and "/home/mine/".

Comment: That is the behavior specified for the GNU version of the function! See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/basename.3.html "The GNU version never modifies its argument, and returns the empty string when path has a trailing slash, and in particular also when it is "/"." If you don't want the broken GNU behavior, don't ask for it...

Comment: OK - there had better be a good reason for the GNU to go off on its own tangent.  I'll make a note of that peculiarity.  I can sympathize with 'not modifying the argument'.  I have my own prefixed version that gets a sized buffer to copy the basename into, and it has a `const char *` argument for the input.

Comment: For functions like this, it really just makes the most sense to write your own with the exact semantics you expect.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but I think Roman is asking how to ensure the GNU version of these functions are used.  I'm having a similar issue -- in that path is being modified even though libgen.h is not included.  As R.. mentioned, it's simple to write your own, however I don't understand why I would do this if the GNU versions do what I need?

Comment: @J.AndrewLaughlin In cases like this you write your own one because if the source changes, the compiler may include the wrong _basename()_ without giving you any notice, breaking the code that worked and did not change.

Comment: As I understand, there is some complex history behind `basename()`.  I think most first-time users of the C function `basename()` expect it to behave similar to GNU coreutils command tool `/usr/bin/basename`.  Even then, the treatment of leading `//` is a bit weird!

Answer (score 4):

According to the man page you should do

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
```

If you get the POSIX version, libgen.h is probably already included before that point. You may want to include `-D_GNU_SOURCE` in the CPPFLAGS for compilation:

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE ....
```

Compare: [POSIX Version](https://godbolt.org/z/EEMfMM8sY) vs [GNU Version](https://godbolt.org/z/Pc6TxK3K7) on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: simplified more specific answer

Comment: 3 lines gives me __xpg_basename@@GLIBC_2.0, no libgen gives me basename@@GLIBC_2.0 (courtesy of nm). not defining GNU_SO
URCE gives me basename@@GLIBC_2.0 but warns of  initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: I think -D_GNU_SOURCE just does the same as defining _GNU_SOURCE and it warns if I do both.

Comment: @Roman: -D_GNU_SOURCE does the same _BUT_ at a different time. This is exactly the difference I'm talking about. The pointer conversion warning, is just the pointer conversion warning. You can fix that by provining the expected argument type.

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tested exactly this code (trying both #define _GNU_SOURCE and -D_GNU_SOURCE) and I get only the POSIX version.

Comment: @AdrianLopez then you're likely doing something wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/44GW63Wb9 vs https://godbolt.org/z/TW9baTbqe

Comment: Your examples don't match the code you posted in your answer. Including both <string.h> and <libgen.h> like in your answer will cause the POSIX version of basename() to be declared whether you define _GNU_SOURCE or not (see links to examples below). Also, your examples' output saying basename("/") "should be empty on POSIX" is incorrect. It's the other way around: POSIX basename should return a single slash and GNU basename should return an empty string.

https://godbolt.org/z/9d7oefT15
https://godbolt.org/z/od5eYM7T9
https://godbolt.org/z/1x7YKnGar

Comment: @AdrianLopez you're quite right. Fixed both.

Answer (score 2):

After examining `libgen.h`, I'm pretty sure I have a warning-free and error-free solution:

```
/* my C program */
#define _GNU_SOURCE     /*  for GNU version of basename(3) */
#include <libgen.h>     /*  for dirname(3) */
#undef basename         /*  (snide comment about libgen.h removed) */
#include <string.h>     /*  for basename(3) (GNU version) and strcmp(3) */

/* rest of C program... */
```

With the `#undef` line, now my program includes `dirname(3)` from `libgen.h` and the GNU version of `basename(3)` from `string.h`.

No compiler warnings/errors from either `gcc` (version 4.5.2) or `clang` (version 3.3).

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it should come with a word of warning: there exists no GNU-specific version of dirname, so calling dirname and GNU basename on a path such as "/home/" (with a trailing slash) will give you a dirname of "/" and an empty string for the basename, completely dropping the "home" component of the path. For this reason, I think the best advice would be to avoid the GNU version of basename altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're building with the GNU C library, rather than your system's (presumed) POSIX-compatible default.

This is often set in the GCC spec file. Use the <kbd>-v</kbd> option to show the current settings:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crazy basename and dirname have two versions.

We worked at a big project, it looks like these two apis already caused
potentially bugs. So we marked "basename" "dirname" as deprecated for warning if
someone use it:

```
#ifdef basename
__attribute__ ((deprecated))
char *__xpg_basename(char *path);
#else
__attribute__ ((deprecated))
char *basename(const char *path);
#endif

 __attribute__ ((deprecated))
char *dirname(char *path);
```

We also try to introduce a base c foundation library such as glib or libcork,
but it looks like too heavy. So we write a tiny library for this purpose, it
implementation like this:

```
#include <libgen.h>       // for dirname
#include <linux/limits.h> // for PATH_MAX
#include <stdio.h>        // for snprintf
#include <string.h>       // for basename
#include <stdbool.h>      // for bool

bool get_basename(const char *path, char *name, size_t name_size) {
  char path_copy[PATH_MAX] = {'\0'};
  strncpy(path_copy, path, sizeof(path_copy) - 1);
  return snprintf(name, name_size, "%s", basename(path_copy)) < name_size;
}

bool get_dirname(const char *path, char *name, size_t name_size) {
  char path_copy[PATH_MAX] = {'\0'};
  strncpy(path_copy, path, sizeof(path_copy) - 1);
  return snprintf(name, name_size, "%s", dirname(path_copy)) < name_size;
}
```

Then we replace all `basename` `dirname` call with `get_basename` `get_dirname`.